# do while loop without {}

Tags: c++, do-while

Is the below syntax of writing `do while` loop containing single statement without using braces like other loops namely `while, for, etc.` correct? I'm getting the required output but I want to know whether this has any undefined behavior.

```
int32_t i = 1;
do 
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
while(++i <= 10);
```

Comment: c,c#,c++,java all are of same behavior for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original resource to answer this question should be the C++ standards: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards.
In C++17, 9.5 Iteration statements [stmt.iter] says `do` takes a statement:

> do statement while ( expression ) ;

So this is definitely fine.

9.3 Compound statement or block [stmt.block] says

> So that several statements can be used where one is expected, the compound statement (also, and equivalently,
> called “block”) is provided.

so people tend/like to use `{ ... }` for `do` statements.

Answer (score 2):

The grammar for a do-while loop is given [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter#general-1):

> do *statement* while ( *expression* ) ;

The grammar for a [statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:statement) allows for a [*expression-statement*](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement):

> statement:
>
> > attribute-specifier-seq opt expression-statement
>
> expression-statement:
>
> > expression opt ;

So the body of a do-while doesn't need to be inside `{}`, and your code is valid.

Answer (score 1):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) indicates that it's the same with `do while` as it is with `while` and `if` and so on.

The relevant syntax:

> *attr* (optional) **do** *statement* **while** ( *expression* ) ;
>
> - attr(C++11) -   any number of attributes
> - expression  -   any expression which is contextually convertible to bool.
>   This expression is evaluated after each iteration, and if it yields false, the loop is exited.
> - statement   -   any statement, typically a
>   compound statement, which is the body of the loop

The key here is that a statement is typically a compound statement enclosed in curly braces, but not necessarily so.

As with those constructions, I would tend to prefer braces even when it is only a single line, but it's good to know that it works.

Answer (score 1):

The body of a `do`-`while` construct must be a [*statement*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements).

> `attr(optional) do statement while ( expression ) ;`
>
> attr(C++11) - any number of attributes
>
> expression - any expression which is contextually convertible to bool. This expression is evaluated after each iteration, and if it yields false, the loop is exited.
>
> **statement - any statement, typically a compound statement, which is the body of the loop**

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) notes that this statement is usually a *compound statement*, which is a block surrounded by curly braces.

> Compound statements or blocks are brace-enclosed sequences of statements.

However, this statement can also just be an expression terminated by a semi-colon, which is the case in your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one statement inside the `do-while` or `if` or `for`, the braces aren't necessary

i.e.

```
do
  statement;   
while (cond)
```

is the same as

```
do   
{
  statement;   
}
while (cond)
```

One the other hand

Likewise

```
if(cond)
     statement;
```

is same

```
if(cond)
{
     statement;
}
```

If you write

```
if(cond)
     statement1;
     statement2;
```

Then this will considered as

```
if(cond)
{
     statement1;
}
statement2;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's completely fine!
Any loop in C++ which expects curly braces and doesn't find them takes the first line into consideration and move on.

Comment: This is not necessarily true, for example with function and class definitions.